# Asterisk ChanSpy solution

Tags: asterisk

I need to be able to have caller A be connected to B in Asterisk, and then caller C be able to call another number to listen in on the conversation between A and B.
However, A needs to have the option to be muted from C hearing his side of the conversation 
ie. in that situation C will only be able to hear B.
I have this all working with Asterisk ChanSpy except that the ChanSpy 'o' option mutes B, and not A.
How can I prevent C from listening to A, but still listen to B ?

Answer (score 0):

Every bridged call in asterisk have 2 channel associcated.

You can control in chanspy which one channel you want to listen. So use it(see ChanSpy doc for more info, no way help you without your dialplan).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to target the other channel with ChanSpy and use the o option. If that's not possible, you might try capital W, but this would enable caller C to talk to A but not hear him.

From the [docs](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_ChanSpy):

> W - Enable private whisper mode, so the spying channel can talk to the spied-on channel but cannot listen to that channel.

Since you probably don't want caller A to hear caller C (which this option would permit), you might use VOLUME to "mute" caller C. (untested, try AGC if VOLUME doesn't work)

```
exten => 1,1,Set(VOLUME(tx)=0)
```